# Determining encryption method from public key and cipher text

Tags: security, encryption-asymmetric

I have a public key encoded as Base64. I tried decoding it as ASN.1 and I can see it consists of two parts: a 2048 bit integer and the integer 65537. I also have a Base64 encoded cipher text encrypted with that public key. Moreover I also know the clear text string that corresponds to the cipher text but I'm not sure which processing (if any) has been applied to the clear text before encryption (e.g. which charset has been used to encode the string).

I'm looking for a way to determine the type of the key and more importantly, the encryption method (algorithm, mode and padding). I tried brute force (i.e. encrypting and comparing computed and received cipher texts) with Java assuming algorithm is RSA but I'm not able not find a match. I'm probably not trying all combinations.

I'm already bruteforcing the following:

- Charsets
- Ciphers (probably not covering all)

Any idea?

---

The public looks like an RSA key, therefore my issue is mostly trying all possible `(mode,padding)` combinations. Is there a way to iterate all possibilities? The other possibility is that a pre processing is applied to the clear text before encryption - any "standard" pre processing for a string before encryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an RSA key almost certainly.

But your approach will not work: if you encrypt the same message twice with RSA, you will get different results.  That's because RSA involves random padding (see [PKCS #1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447)), which is a requirement for the security of the design (to stop attacks like the one you are attempting) -- see footnote.

**Bottom line**: You won't be able to tell how exactly it was encrypted with the information you have, assuming you don't make a cryptographic breakthrough.

Footnote: The security requirement that prevents what you are trying to do was detailed in the seminal cryptographic paper [Probabilistic Encryption](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/cis/pubs/shafi/1984-jcss.pdf).  Among many requirements, they suggested that even if only a single bit was encrypted, you should not be able to brute force (i.e. try both 0 and 1 in this case) to see which value encrypts to the ciphertext that you captured.  The PKCS #1 standard was built with these considerations in mind.

Comment: Great - so I'm on the right track (I don't need to break anything here - I just want to be sure that I would be able to encrypt the data myself as the server expects it to be i.e. RSA_ECB_PKCS1Padding I guess?). However, I don't understand how the server will be able to decrypt the cipher using the private key if there is random padding generated by the client?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache that might be how it is implemented, or there are other possibilities depending upon the version of PKCS #1 used in the server.  The server will remove the random padding following the PKCS standard.  For example, in PKCS #1 v1.5, the padding is random nonzero bytes followed by a zero byte marking the end of the padding.  The server just searches for the zero byte and knows that the plaintext follows the zero byte.  OAEP is more complicated, but all you need to know is that the server knows what to do.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the public key is provided, the algorithm is typically provided along with it (e.g. as another field within the certificate). Usually the intention is for any client to be able to use the public key, so providing the algorithm is consistent with that purpose.

If for some reason the key and its metadata have become separated, it is likely you can just look at the key's data structure and figure out the algorithm. For example, any key that is stored as an OpenSSH key will follow [RFS 4523](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-6.6) which includes a header specifying the algorithim. An RSA public key will contain the exponent and modulus. An ECC key will contain two 32-byte numbers. Etc.

Comment: It looks like it is an RSA key - the presence of a 2048 bit integer plus an additional integer with value 65537. My question is more about the encryption mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing terms from two different technologies. "Mode" and "padding" refer to symmetric ciphers, not asymmetric ciphers like public key cryptography. It's not necessarily wrong since the typical approach is to write the public key, then generate a random session key for a symmetric cipher (e.g., AES) and encrypt it using the public key, then encrypt the plaintext with the random session key, then finally add any message digest. (If you add an HMAC you should use a different keypair than then one used to encrypt a modified session key and it should be a digest of the ciphertext, not the plaintext.) The cipher and mode will be encoded somehow but it will almost certainly use magic values. (e.g., cipher 3, mode 1) and you'll be expected to know how to interpret those values.

Do you know what produced the ciphertext? Does it produce a standard format that you can find documented somewhere, or is it homebrew?

As for figuring out the details of the algorithm and mode from just the ciphertext all I can say is "good luck". The spooks may have tools to help figure this out but these ciphers are designed to produce output that looks like random data. Unless they're using ECB and have repeating plaintext it will be very opaque.

Comment: I can tell for sure that asymmetric encryption is used here since there is no generation of symmetric key - probably because there is no need for session like with SSL. I heard about the terms mode and padding when writing bruteforce code with Java and I see I need to provide both parameters in order to encrypt.

Comment: Padding is used in both asymmetric crypto and symmetric crypto, but it is a different type.  For symmetric, you normally use PKCS #7, which Java likes to call PKCS #5.  For asymmetric RSA, the padding is defined in [PKCS #1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447), which has various versions that include different padding schemes (eg OAEP = optimal asymmetric crypto PADDING).